# Finding the headers for values in Json files

Tags: python, json, list

Hi I've got json data that looks something like this:

```
{
  "content": {
    "Header 1": [
      {
        "name": "Name1",

        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Name2",

        }
      }
    ],
    "Header 2": [
      {
        "name": "Name3",

        }
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

I'm looking to convert this into lists that look something like this:

```
header1 = ["Name1", "Name2"]
header2 = ["Name3"]
```

So far I've been able to get all the names that I want using objectpath.

```
from importlib.resources import path
import json
from unicodedata import name
import objectpath

path = (r"C:\Users\path\example.json")

with open(path) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    
tree_obj = objectpath.Tree(data)

names = list(tree_obj.execute('$..name'))

print (names)
```

But I've been unable to get the appropriate headers for each name as it appears to be nested under the 'content' header

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: That data is not syntactically valid.  I assume you have deleted lines after the "name" key, because the curly bracket that follows is wrong.

Comment: Yup you'd be right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you ask.  Just iterate through the keys of "content", and grab the keys in the subobjects.

```
import json

jsonx = """{
  "content": {
    "Header 1": [
      {
        "name": "Name1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Name2"
      }
    ],
    "Header 2": [
      {
        "name": "Name3"
      }
    ]
  }
}"""

data = json.loads(jsonx)
gather = {}

for k, v in data["content"].items():
    k1 = k.lower().replace(' ','')
    v1 = [vv['name'] for vv in v]
    gather[k1] = v1

print(gather)
```

Output:

```
{'header1': ['Name1', 'Name2'], 'header2': ['Name3']}
```

And for those who like one-liners:

```
gather = dict( 
    (k.lower().replace(' ',''),[vv['name'] for vv in v])
    for k, v in data["content"].items() )
```